# Blender 2.8 in Windows 10

Tags: windows, installation

I'm a long time Blender user, though not very technical.  Currently have 2.79 installed and working well.          When I try to use 2.8, it starts to boot, shows me a blank screen and closes.  I can open it on my Linux system, but not on Windows 10, 64 bit 16 gig of mem.  My graphics card is an ATI Radeon Pro WX7100 with 32 gig dedicated memory. Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: AMD specifies 8 GB as the memory size for the Radeon Pro WX7100 cards. What do you mean by '32 gig dedicated memory'?

Comment: He probably means that he has 32 gigs of his hard drive partitioned for ram-type usage

Comment: The Radeon pro has 2 wx7100 devices, each with 16 gig.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about issues with unfinished experimental software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2.8 is not released yet. I don't think it is very reasonable to expect technical support for installing software that is unfinished yet. You could try reinstalling graphics drivers, any other drivers that are not up to date on the PC, also you could try to re-download the latest build once in every few days and try if that works. Else than that - it is experimental software at this stage. Don't be surprised if it does not work yet.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I agree, and no expectation.  Just checking to see if anyone had an answer. I will continue to try with new releases.

Comment: FWIW this May 2018 report of something similar https://developer.blender.org/T54990 was answered with "2.8 bug reporting currently limited to module team members".  With 2.8 almost out the door I think that response might be out of date, but didn't see anything else.  I'm having the same issue.

Comment: SOLVED: (for me at least, June 2019) by moving unzipped blender folder from `C:\Users\TBrown02\Desktop\blender-2.80.0-git.12da679fa094-windows64` to `U:\tmp\blrn`.  So some windows path issue, rather than blender related.

Comment: Were you trying to run it straight after downloading from the zip archive without extracting it?